# Why the different result between a while and for loop

Tags: loops, for-loop, while-loop

I have just entered the world of coding and am learning all about loops. I just learnt about for and while loops but don't understand why the return different results. Can someone please explain the logic in a lay person's terms.

/* for loop code */

```
$counter = 0;
$start = 1;
$end = 11;

for($start;$start<$end;start++) {
$counter=$counter+1;
print $counter;
}
```

The result I get is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 , 8, 9 , 10

/* while loop code */

```
$start=0;
$end=11;

while($start<end) {
$start=$start+1;
print $start;
}
```

The result I get is 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11

Why is that the while loop returns a result of 1 through to 11 whilst the for loop returns a result of 1 through to 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `for` case `$start` starts from 1 but in `while` case `$start` starts from 0.

Working on `for` -

```
 iteration    $start      $start<$end     counter   print   start++        
    1           1            1<11           1         1        2
    2           2            2<11           2         2        3
    3           3            3<11           3         3        4
    4           4            4<11           4         4        5
    5           5            5<11           5         5        6
    6           6            6<11           6         6        7
    7           7            7<11           7         7        8
    8           8            8<11           8         8        9
    9           9            9<11           9         9        10
   10           10          10<11          10         10       11
   11           11          11<11 
                          // (false) break
```

Similarly work on the `while` loop. It's a paper-pencil exercise.

Comment: Okay but if I don't start from 0 then the result would range between 2 through to 11 as opposed to 1 through to 10.

Comment: Thanks Mahesh. I gave that a go with the code below

$start=1;
$end=11;
 
 for($start;$start<$end;$start++) {
  print $start. "<br>";
 }

The result I get is 1 through to 10 however if I try the following with the while loop code I get the result 2 through 11

$start=1;
 $end=11;
 
 while($start<$end) {
  $start=$start+1;
  print $start;
 }

My question is that that initialize at the same values i.e. 1, the end with the same value i.e. 11 and have the same counter i.e. start=start+1 but the results are different.

Answer (score 2):

The increment in a for loop executes after the first loop.

Try this:

```
$start=1;
$end=11;

while($start<end) {
    print $start;
    $start=$start+1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the two counters are not initialized at the same value, try the first one with

```
$start = 1;
```

Comment: Yes if I start them at the same value e.g. 1, the while loop returns the result 2 through to 11 when specifically I have noted that I would like it to be less than 11 i.e. 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11

Comment: Actually you specified than `$start` should be less than 11 not `$counter`

Answer (score 0):

On the last iteration of the while loop, 10<11, then you add 1 to 10, so it equals 11.  But you are already in your loop.  So it prints out.  Next time through, 11<11 is false, so it exits immediately.

Now, if you want it to work, move $start=$start+1; to AFTER the print statement.

In addition, I think you are confusing yourself.  In 1 example you are printing out "$start", and in another, you are printing out "$counter".